# Sitecore experience profile search extension

Tags: experience-profile

Sitecore version: 9.1 Update-1

By default, it is possible to search with Email, First Name, Last Name (after enabling PII indexing) in the Experience Profile search. In our implementation, we have created custom facet for each contact eg. Customer ID. We want to enable Experience Profile search with custom facet, how can we extend this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is very hard since the search controller for XP is not extendable. You have to decompile the code, override a config. And that make upgrades hard.